# Warnings for unused results of side-effect free methods in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I don't assign result of `BigDecimal.divide()` method to a variable, I get a nice warning from IntelliJ Idea:

> Result of BigDecimal.divide() is ignored.

Can I somehow get the same warning for my own (side-effect free) functions? Something like assigning a Java annotation to my function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the "Result of method call ignored" inspection. By default, it only reports a couple of special methods, including all methods of `java.lang.BigDecimal`. In the inspection configuration you can add other classes and methods that should be reported in this way.

[image]

The "Report all ignored non-library calls" check box selects all classes in your project.

If you want to use annotations, you can annotate single methods or entire classes with the [JSR 305 annotation](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305)

```
javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue
```

Since IDEA 2016.3 you can even use the [error prone annotation](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.errorprone/error_prone_annotations)

```
com.google.errorprone.annotations.CanIgnoreReturnValue
```

to exclude single methods from return value checking. Using both annotations, you can write a class like this:

```
import javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue;
import com.google.errorprone.annotations.CanIgnoreReturnValue;

@CheckReturnValue
class A {
  String a() { return "a"; }

  @CanIgnoreReturnValue
  String b() { return "b"; }

  void run() {
    a(); // Warning
    b(); // No warning
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your example but `CanIgnoreReturnValue` does not seem to suppress the warning in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.2.

Comment: @PerMildner: It is important, that you use `CanIgnoreReturnValue` from Errorprone package. Other `CanIgnoreReturnValues` are not supported at the moment. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-221360