# How can ignoring of return value be marked in Java code?

Tags: java

There is C convention to mark that function is called for side effects only and in this particular invocation we are not interested in returning value:

```
(void) getSomethingAndDoAction(...);
```

Are there any equivalent in Java?

Comment: Add a comment saying so?

Comment: IMHO, a method having side effects is bad design. Make the method void itself. Then it's clear that it must have a side effect.

Comment: @FredK Probably. I can miss some cool `@Ignore` annotation though...

Comment: Actually, I'm too misunderstood,why do not use `void` method?

Comment: I see you mean something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689677/why-cast-unused-return-values-to-void, but do you actually get some warning from a linter? You may want to consider naming the linter too in that case as any kind of suppression is likely going to be linter-specific.

Comment: This is a fine question that does not deserve to be closed. In C, casting an expression to `void` assures the compiler that you are intentionally ignoring the return value. Java does not have `void` casting, so a different solution would be needed. Whether or not one exists in Java is not grounds for closing a question.

Comment: Example of use case: a method which "has side effects" (that is, does something, e.g. add rows in a database) returning, say, how many rows were actually inserted. Now, the method is used in 2 places. In one, I need to know how many rows, hence I check the return value; in another, for some reason I can disregard the num of inserted rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Error Prone project](https://errorprone.info/) has a [`@CheckReturnValue` annotation](https://errorprone.info/bugpattern/CheckReturnValue) that can be used for this purpose.

This would make it **a compile-time error** to ignore the return value, **unless** you suppress the error using an annotation: `@SuppressWarnings("CheckReturnValue")`

Comment: See also [Warnings for unused results of side-effect free methods in IntelliJ Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41115736/5221149), which shows that IntelliJ supports this.