# apply CheckReturnValue to entire project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, static-analysis, findbugs, errorprone

I work on a large legacy Java 8 (Android) application. We recently found a bug that was caused by an ignored result of method. Specifically a caller of a `send()` method didn't take the right actions when it the sending failed. It's been fixed but now I want to add some static analysis to help find if other existing bugs of the same nature exist in our code. And additionally, to prevent new bugs of the same nature from being added in the future.

We already use Find Bugs, PMD, Checkstyle, Lint, and SonarQube. So I figured that one of these probably already has the check I'm looking for, but it just needs to be enabled. But after a few hours of searching and testing, I don't think that's the case.

For reference, this is the code I was testing with:

```
public class Application {
    public status void main(String[] args) {
        foo(); // I want this to be caught
        Bar aBar = new Bar();
        aBar.baz(); // I want this to be caught
    }
    
    static boolean foo() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis() % 2 == 0;
    }
}

public class Bar {
    boolean baz() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis() % 2 == 0;
    }
}
```

I want to catch this on the **caller** side since some callers may use the value while others do not. (The `send()` method described above was this case)

I found the following existing static analysis rules but they only seem to apply to very specific circumstances to avoid false positives and not work on my example:

- [Return values from functions without side effects should not be ignored](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2201) (only for immutable classes in the Java API)
- [Method ignores exceptional return value](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#RV_RETURN_VALUE_IGNORED_BAD_PRACTICE) (only for known methods like File.delete())
- [Method ignores return value](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#RV_RETURN_VALUE_IGNORED) (only for methods annotated with javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue I think...)
- [Method ignores return value, is this OK?](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#RV_RETURN_VALUE_IGNORED_INFERRED) (only when the return value is the same type as the type the method is invoked on)
- [Return value of method without side effect is ignored](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#RV_RETURN_VALUE_IGNORED_NO_SIDE_EFFECT) (only when the method does not produce any effect other than return value)

So far the best option seems to be #3 but it requires me to annotate EVERY method or class in my HUGE project. Java 9+ seems to allow annotating at the package-level but that's not an option for me. Even if it was, the project has A LOT of packages. I really would like a way to configure this to be applied to my whole project via one/few locations instead needing to modify every file.

Lastly I came across [this Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41116890/2882883) answer that showed me that IntelliJ has this check with a "Report all ignored non-library calls" check. Doing this seems to work as far as highlighting in the IDE. But I want this to cause CI fail. I found there's a way to trigger this via command line [using intelliJ tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/command-line-code-inspector.html#inspection-profiles) but this still outputs an XML/JSON file and I'll need to write custom code to parse that output. I'd also need to install IDE tools onto the CI machine which seems like overkill.

Does anyone know of a better way to achieve what I want? I can't be the first person to only care about false negatives and not care about false positives. I feel like it should be manageable to have any return value that is currently being unused to either be logged or have it explicitly stated that the return value is intentionally ignored it via an annotation or assigning to a variable convention like they do in [Error Prone](https://errorprone.info/bugpattern/CheckReturnValue)

Answer (score 1):

Scenarios like the one you describe invariably give rise to a substantial software defect (a true bug in every respect); made more frustrating and knotty because the code fails silently, and which allowed the problem to remain hidden. Your desire to identify any similar hidden defects (and correct them) is easy to understand; however, (I humbly suggest) static code analysis may not be the best strategy:

- Working from the concerns you express in your question: a `CheckReturnValue` rule runs a high risk of producing a cascade of `//Ignore` code comments, rule `violationSuppress` clauses, and/or `@suppressRule` annotations that far outnumber the rule's positive defect detection count.
- The Java programming language further increases the likelihood of a high rule suppression count, after taking Java garbage collection into consideration and assessing how garbage collection effects software development. Working from the understanding that Java garbage collection is based on object instance reference counting, that only instances with a reference count of 0 (zero) are eligible for garbage collection, it makes perfect sense for Java developers to avoid unnecessary references, and to naturally adopt the practice of ignoring unimportant method call return values. The ignored instances will simply fall off of the local call stack, most will reach a reference count of 0 (zero), immediately become eligible for and quickly undergo garbage collection.

Shifting now from a negative perspective to positive, I offer alternatives, for your consideration, that (I believe) will improve your results, as well as your probability to reach a successful outcome.

- Based on your description of the scenario and resulting defect / bug, it feels like the proximate root cause of the problem is a unit testing failure or an integration testing failure. The implementation of a send operation that may (and almost certainly will at some point) fail, both unit testing and integration testing absolutely should have incorporated multiple possible failure scenarios and verified failure scenario handling. I obviously don't know, but I'm willing to bet that if you focus on creating and running unit tests and integration tests, the quality of the system will improve at every step, the improvements will be clearly evident, and you may very well uncover some or all of the hidden bugs that are the cause of your current concern, trepidation, stress, and worry.
- Consider keeping the gist of your current static code analysis research alive, but shift your approach in a new direction. The first time I read your question, I was struck by the realization that the code checks you would like to perform exist in multiple unrelated locations across the code base and are quickly becoming overly complex, the specific details of the checks are different in many section of code, and each of the special cases make the overall effort unrealistic. Basically, what you would like to implement represents a cross-cutting goal that falls across a sizable section of the code base, and the implementation details have made what is a fairly simple good idea ridiculously complex. Your question is almost a textbook example of a problem that is best implemented taking a cross-cutting aspect-oriented approach.

If you have the time and interest, please take a look at the [AspectJ](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) framework, maybe code a few exploratory aspects, and let me know what you think. I'd like to hear your thoughts, if you feel like having a geeky dev conversation at some point. I really hope this is helpful-

Comment: Thanks for the great reply. I agree with the risk of a suppression explosion, but I think it is manageable. Our company prevents merges without a code review, and we already fail suppressions that don't have good reasons. 
As for GC, that seems to line up with the Error Prone approach I mentioned. I assume the memory pressure impact will not be an issue for us. My hope is also that more often we'll just re-write things instead of using that approach though.
I agree completely that unit testing is another approach but it seems to rely more on coder/reviewer skill/diligence...

Comment: ...instead of *automatically* knowing if this type of issue is covered or not. 
Coverage thresholds might help a bit but seems like a blunt tool in this regard. (currently we are 25% coverage on 750,000 LOC)
I agree with the claims of effort if we want to address instances of this existing in our code (currently 1170), but likely less so if we just want to use thresholds to prevent new ones from coming in.
I'll try and dig into AOP and AspectJ over the weekend and get back to you on the last point as I'm not too familiar with either at the moment. (I've always meant to learn but never did)

Answer (score 1):

You may use the intelliJ IDEA's inspection: **Java | Probable bugs | Result of method call ignored** with "*Report all ignored non-library calls*" option enabled. It catches both cases provided in your code sample.

Comment: yes, I mentioned that in my post. But the question was how to integrate this into CI to enforce this, not just have highlights in the IDE (Ideally without needing to install the IDE on CI machines)